# Can't get images to work in django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm getting a 404 error when trying to serve user uploaded files in local. I've tried a lot of suggestions from the forums but I can't get it to work.
This is the error I can see on the logs. The images get uploaded properly to media/images but when I try to use that same image I get a 404 not found. I've tried to put the absolute path and didn't work either. Could anybody please help me? Thanks

```
[03/Feb/2018 23:32:00] "GET /idealistos/30/ HTTP/1.1" 200 483
Not Found: /media/images/_D3L8637.jpg
[03/Feb/2018 23:32:01] "GET /media/images/_D3L8637.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2239
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
# Media files
MEDIA_ROOT = 'media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminDateWidget

# Create your models here.
class Anuncio(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    foto = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='images/')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.datetime.now())


def __str__(self):
    return self.title
def __unicode__(self):
    return price


class AnuncioForm(ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Anuncio

    fields = ['title', 'description', 'price', 'city', 'state', 'country','postcode','foto']
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django import forms
from django.utils import timezone
#from django.template import loader
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from .models import Anuncio, AnuncioForm

#Creates a list from a model. Used for the ad index view.
class AnuncioList(ListView):

model = Anuncio

#Creates a detail view of the Ad
def detail(request, anuncio_id):
try:
    anuncio_detalle = get_object_or_404(Anuncio, pk=anuncio_id)
    #anuncio_detalle = Anuncio.objects.get(pk=anuncio_id)
except Anuncio.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404("Question does not exist")
return render(request, 'idealistos/detail.html', {'anuncio_detalle':anuncio_detalle})


def add_form(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AnuncioForm(request.POST,request.FILES)

    if form.is_valid():
        new_add = form.save()
        new_add.pub_date = timezone.now()



        return redirect ('idealistos:index')

else:
    form = AnuncioForm()

return render(request, 'idealistos/create_add.html', {'form':form,})
```

**url.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from idealistos.views import AnuncioList

app_name ='idealistos'
urlpatterns = [
# ex: /idealistos/
path('', AnuncioList.as_view(), name='index'),
# ex: /idealistos/5/
path('<int:anuncio_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
#ex: /idealistos/add_form
path('add_form/', views.add_form, name='add_form'),

]
         urlpatterns+=static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**Template**

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet"    href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>

<body>


{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'idealistos/idealistos.css' %}" />


<h1>{{ anuncio_detalle }}</h1>
<ul>
<li>{{ anuncio_detalle.description }}</li>
<li>{{ anuncio_detalle.city }}, {{ anuncio_detalle.country }} CP:{{ anuncio_detalle.postcode }}</li>
<li>{{ anuncio_detalle.pub_date }}</li>
<img src={{anuncio_detalle.foto.url}}>
</ul>

</body>
```

Comment: I doubt it makes sense to have a relative path for MEDIA_ROOT. Make it an absolute file path like you did for STATIC_ROOT.

Comment: I've swapped to this and now images don't get uploaded 
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'media')
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

path for foto in model is 
foto = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='images/')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try giving `MEDIA_ROOT` and serving in `urls.py` when `DEBUG=True`.

**models.py**

```
foto = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True, blank=True)
```

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.static import serve
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
   #Other Urls
   . . . . .
   . . . . . 

   # admin
   url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT
        }),
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
Still not working. 
If I use MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'media') 
images don't get written to media/images/.
My form has the following:

foto = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='images/')

Should I change that attribute?

Comment: thanks. I used ImageField (had to install Pillow) and changed models.py, settings.py and url.py as you said. Now images are getting uploaded to ~/django/media/images properly but the path to the image is incorrect:


Not Found: /idealistos/44/images/_D3L8458_lF9Nac1.jpg
[04/Feb/2018 01:37:31] "GET /idealistos/44/images/_D3L8458_lF9Nac1.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 3101

Comment: The current path, idealistos/46/images/23658378_1145199562278028_3235145770201548382_n.jpg, didn't match any of these.

Comment: Page not found (404)
Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://localhost:8000/idealistos/46/images/23658378_1145199562278028_3235145770201548382_n.jpg

Comment: I don't know why this 46 is coming??

Comment: That's the post ID. (Anuncio.id). If I create a new post that number increments, so next post is 47.

Comment: But why it is coming in image_url. Just right click on html page see source code of the html page and see what is the source there.

Comment: I got it working by putting this on the main url.py file. I was putting it under the apps url.py hence the error:

'+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)'

Comment: That I had already mentioned, earlier that you have to put it in **base urls.py**, thats why I gave `admin/` url path to make you understand. But anyways it is nice to hear that, it is working fine now.

Comment: Sorry I'm very new to python and django! Thanks so much for your help. I will read more carefully next time!

Comment: @green_hornet, That's ok everyone starts afresh at some point of time. You will get better once you start using more and more. You can select the answer, if it helped you. Thanks a lot for all the cooperation

Answer (score 0):

I hope that you are seeing the uploaded file correctly.

For local development, try adding the following in your base urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG is True:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Hi, yes I can see the image uploaded to /media/images. However seeing this error now. 
 `Page not found (404)
    Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://localhost:8000/idealistos/46/images/23658378_1145199562278028_3235145770201548382_n.jpg

Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^arduinogui/
    ^idealistos/ [name='index']
    ^idealistos/ <int:anuncio_id>/ [name='detail']
    ^idealistos/ add_form/ [name='add_form']
    ^idealistos/ ^media\/(?P<path>.*)$
    ^idealistos/ ^media\/(?P<path>.*)$`